# Имейл рыссылки.Помогите пожалуйста с имейл рассылкой

Tags: html, css, email, foundation

Столкнулся c e-mail рассылкой. Пытался сделать их с помощью foundation, возникли проблемы с git. Скачал готовый темплейт, но там стили css в отдельном файле.

Почтовый клиент их не видит.

https://github.com/philwareham/responsive-email

Как вы правильно подгружаете стили для e-mail рассылок?

И еще вопросы:

1. МОЖНО ли настроить foundation без `npm` и прочей фигни?
2. Как заинлайнить отдельный css?
3. Какой сервис лучше для проверки совместимости писем с браузерами и клиентами?

Answer (score 0):

> Как вы правильно подгружаете стили для e-mail рассылок?

Никак. В емейлах допускаются только инлайн-стили и верстка в духе HTML начала века.